# Union of file directories in Linux

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to do an incremental backup of a system we have, and am moving a lot of attachment files in many directories. I would like to merge my current attachments with my new attachments. Example:

Production Attachments Directory:

```
Dir A/ Dir B/ File 1, File 2
```

Attachments Backup Directory:

```
Dir A/ Dir B/ File 3, File 4
```

After Merge I would like to see:

```
Dir A/ Dir B/ File 1, File 2, File 3, File 4
```

The directory has hundreds of folders like this, so I would like to do it recursively. Is there a command in Linux/Unix that can do this? I have looked into commands like Union, but I am not sure if that will solve this problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem because my solution seems too simple, but..

cp -R (recurse) may provide you what you seek.

Taking your backup copy first and create a duplicate :

*cp -R [backup directory] merged_attachments*

Then force and recurse the production copy (so you have the latest production version in case you have a conflict) :

*cp -fR [production directory]/* merged_attachments*

You will wind up with your final merged_attachments directory containing the same structure both source directories.

You could accomplish the same thing if you wanted to copy the backup into the production directory with :

*cp -nR [backup directory]/* [production directory]*

Using the noclobber flag so you don't overwrite production files with the backup version.